# How to create mule client?

Tags: java, mule

I want to create mule client by java as Mule guide
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-the-mule-client#sts=Using the Mule Client.
But it guide not good, I feel not enough to learn and code. Please help me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to work with the MuleClient is not by creating one but getting it from the MuleContext. In a FunctionalTestCase you would have something like this, for example:

```
MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
```

After that you can start using the client to send messages. Of course, the way of accessing the MuleContext will depend on what Java component you are coding.

HTH

Comment: Sorry but I want to ask: muleContext - where obitan or declare muleContext variable?

Comment: As I mentioned, that depends on the kind of Java component you are coding. Is it a ```FunctionalTestCase```? A ```MessageProcessor```? A ```Callable``` used in a ```component``` element? Each is different, in the latter, for example, you have to take it from the ```MuleEventContext``` provided in the ```onCall``` method you are supposed to override.